# Merge sorting a struct

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct points{
        float axis[2];
        int id;
}Points;

typedef enum{
        SortById,
        SortByXAxis
}SortType;

Points* fill_Array(char* filename, int* length);
void Print_set(Points* set, int number_of_points);
void mergesort(Points* set, int low, int high, int number_of_points,SortType sort);
void merge(Points* set, int low, int middle, int high, int number_of_points,SortType sort);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int length;
    Points *array;
    array=fill_Array(argv[1],&length);
    Print_set(array,length);
    printf("\n\n");
    mergesort(array,0,length,length,SortById);
    Print_set(array,length);
    return 0;
}
Points* fill_Array(char* filename,int* length)
{
    int i;
    Points* array;
    FILE* file=fopen(filename,"r");

    if(file == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    fscanf(file,"%d",length);
    array=malloc(sizeof(Points)* *length);

    for(i = 0; i < *length; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file,"%d %f %f", &(array+i)->id,&(array+i)->axis[0],&(array+i)->axis[1]);
    }
    fclose(file);

    return array;
}

void Print_set(Points *set, int number_of_points)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_points; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %f %f\n",(set+i)->id,(set+i)->axis[0],(set+i)->axis[1]);
    }
}

void mergesort(Points* set,int low,int high,int number_of_points, SortType sort)
{
    int mid1;

    if((high-low)>=1)
    {
        mid1 = (low+high)/2;

        mergesort(set, low, mid1, number_of_points, sort);
        mergesort(set, mid1+1, high, number_of_points, sort);
        merge(set, low, mid1, high, number_of_points, sort);

    }

}
void merge(Points* set, int low, int middle, int high, int number_of_points, SortType sort)
{
        int leftIndex=low;
        int rightIndex=middle;
        int combinedIndex = low;
        Points tempArray[number_of_points];
        int i;

        while(leftIndex <= middle && rightIndex<= high)
        {
            if(set[leftIndex].id <= set[rightIndex].id)
            {
                tempArray[combinedIndex++] = set[leftIndex++];
            }
            else
                tempArray[combinedIndex++] = set[rightIndex++];
        }

        if(leftIndex == middle+1)
        {
            while(rightIndex <= high)
            {
                tempArray[combinedIndex++] = set[rightIndex++];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while(leftIndex <= middle)
            {
                tempArray[combinedIndex++] = set[leftIndex++];
            }
        }

        for( i = low; i < high; i++)
        {
            set[i] = tempArray[i];
        }
}
```

I am trying to perform a merge sort on an input file using a custom merge sort function. The merge sort functions however are not working and print out down below, the first block being the actual input file printed out to make sure fscanf is reading in everything correctly and the second being the printing after the merge functions are run. The functions are duplicating some of the values and are not sorting them either and I cannot find the mistake in the code. Note that the enum will be used to sort either the ids or the first float values I am just trying to get the merge sort to work before I use it to sort either the ids or those values.

```
1 13.000000 7.000000
13 14.000000 6.000000
95 7.000000 13.000000
39 0.000000 20.000000
78 10.000000 10.000000
68 3.000000 17.000000
32 6.000000 14.000000
10 19.000000 1.000000
0 18.000000 2.000000
45 17.000000 3.000000
92 4.000000 16.000000
29 5.000000 15.000000
85 8.000000 12.000000
79 15.000000 5.000000
12 16.000000 4.000000
32 1.000000 19.000000
77 9.000000 11.000000
52 12.000000 8.000000
80 11.000000 9.000000
31 2.000000 18.000000


1 13.000000 7.000000
13 14.000000 6.000000
68 3.000000 17.000000
0 18.000000 2.000000
10 19.000000 1.000000
0 18.000000 2.000000
0 18.000000 2.000000
92 4.000000 16.000000
92 4.000000 16.000000
29 5.000000 15.000000
32 1.000000 19.000000
52 12.000000 8.000000
77 9.000000 11.000000
79 15.000000 5.000000
12 16.000000 4.000000
32 1.000000 19.000000
32 1.000000 19.000000
80 11.000000 9.000000
95 7.000000 13.000000
95 7.000000 13.000000
```

Comment: You're making this *very* hard on yourself. Mergesort partitioning lends itself *beautifully* to the C language in part because of the benefits of pointer arithmetic. And properly done, the `<=` operator need **never** appear in the algorithm, making it *much* easier to understand. [See example live](http://ideone.com/wdraQR).

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have gotten confused about the meaning of your boundary indices.  Consider the initial call to function `mergesort()`:

```
    mergesort(array,0,length,length,SortById);
```

You pass the same value for arguments `high` and `number_of_points`, which is fine, but it implies that `high` represents an *exclusive* upper bound on the indices of the sort range.  The `mergesort()` implementation, however, seems geared for argument `high` to represent an *inclusive* bound.

The confusion continues with your `merge()` function, which is probably the main culprit here.  By taking the passed midpoint value as the start index of the right sub-array, it seems to be expecting the midpoint as an *exclusive* upper bound of the left sub-array, but the current `mergesort()` implementation passes an *inclusive* upper bound.  On the other hand, some of the index comparisons performed by `merge()` are appropriate only if `middle` is an *inclusive* upper bound of the subarray.

In short, you have a muddle.  The basic outline of the algorithm looks fine, but you need to decide (and document for yourself) what your function parameters represent, and reconcile your implementation details with that.  Were I you, I would adopt half-open representation for all intervals, so that lower bounds are always inclusive, and upper bounds always exclusive.  Among other things, that has the advantage that each midpoint value can be interpreted equally correctly as the (exclusive) upper bound of the left half of its subarray or as the (inclusive) lower bound of the right half.

Comment: So for starters it would be best to change the initial mergesort call to

Comment: mergesort(arrray,0,length-1,length,SortById)

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson He was suggesting the opposite, leave the initial mergesort call and change to code to exclude the upper bound from all of the loops, i.e. change `<=` to `<` as appropriate. And check `(high-low) > 1` in mergesort.

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson, user3386109 has correctly characterized my recommendation.  In the end, though, you can choose any mechanism for representing the interval bounds -- even different mechanisms in different functions -- as long as your code is consistent with that choice.

Comment: Well if the bounds are now correct and will only do inclusive on the lower and exclusive on the upper, why is it still not correctly sorting the array?

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson, once you settle on a representation, you need to review your code line by line to ensure that it is everywhere consistent with that choice.  As user3386109 observed, you have not successfully done that.

Comment: mergesort only needs set, low, high as parameters. I recommend making high exclusive (so that the initial call is mergesort(set, 0, count). Then within mergesort you have | mid = (low + high) / 2; | mergesort(set, low, mid); | mergesort(mid, high); | . With these changes to mergesort, the index checks in merge() should be < insetad of <=.

Answer (score -1):

```
    void mergesort(Points* set,int low,int high,int number_of_points, SortType sort)
    {
        int mid1;

        if((high-low)>1)
        {
            mid1 = (low+high)/2;

            mergesort(set, low, mid1, number_of_points, sort);
            mergesort(set, mid1, high, number_of_points, sort);
            merge(set, low, mid1, high, number_of_points, sort);

        }

    }
    void merge(Points* set, int low, int middle, int high, int number_of_points, SortType sort)
    {
            int leftIndex=low;
            int rightIndex=middle;
            int combinedIndex = low;
            Points tempArray[number_of_points];
            int i;

            while(leftIndex <= middle && rightIndex < high)
            {
                if(set[leftIndex].id <= set[rightIndex].id)
                {
                    tempArray[combinedIndex++] = set[leftIndex++];
                }
                else
                    tempArray[combinedIndex++] = set[rightIndex++];
            }

            if(leftIndex == middle+1)
            {
                while(rightIndex < high)
                {
                    tempArray[combinedIndex++] = set[rightIndex++];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                while(leftIndex < middle)
                {
                    tempArray[combinedIndex++] = set[leftIndex++];
                }
            }

            for( i = low; i < high; i++)
            {
                set[i] = tempArray[i];
            }
    }

0 18.000000 2.000000
1 13.000000 7.000000
10 19.000000 1.000000
0 18.000000 2.000000
12 16.000000 4.000000
13 14.000000 6.000000
29 5.000000 15.000000
31 2.000000 18.000000
32 6.000000 14.000000
32 1.000000 19.000000
39 0.000000 20.000000
39 0.000000 20.000000
52 12.000000 8.000000
31 2.000000 18.000000
68 3.000000 17.000000
77 9.000000 11.000000
78 10.000000 10.000000
12 16.000000 4.000000
79 15.000000 5.000000
85 8.000000 12.000000
```

Comment: I see lots of `<=` in that code, and have confirmed that at least one of them is wrong. You need to get all of the ranges right.

Comment: So all of the <= left need to be changed? I can see that the last while loop is wrong but when I did have all < it started printing out garbage values.

Comment: I have changed some of the <= and added the new output but I still cannot figure out why certain parts are sorted but there are still duplicates and such.

Comment: At this point you're just guessing. Take some time to analyze the code, work out some examples on paper, check and double check all of the ranges, etc. You've got the general structure of the code correct, but you're faced with the dreaded off-by-one problem that every C programmer faces. You need to learn how to deal with that, and if I just hand you the correct code, you won't learn.

Comment: So basically every thing else is correct I am just having an upper bound go over by 1, but that does not explain why it is not sorting every thing even if I have duplicates

Comment: I didn't say that. Ranges can be off-by-one at the low end, the high end, or both. So you need to check and double check all the ranges. You can make things easier on yourself by simplifying the dataset. I suggest a file with exactly 8 entries, where the id's are 1 thru 8 in random order, and all of the axis values are 0 to avoid distractions. That way it's easy to predict what the algorithm should do, and you can check what it does do, either with a debugger, or with lots of printfs.